# php or javascript to +1 everyday

Tags: php

Not sure if it matters or not, but I am using wordpress. I am adding the code to the "Raw HTML" in visual composer.

I am looking for a PHP or javascript of a counter that increases by +1 everyday. I am creating a wordpress website, and I need to show number of days since their account has opened.

I found this code on stackoverflow, but it does not seems to work for me.

```
<?php
$now = time();
$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01"); //Starting date
$datediff = floor(($now - $your_date)/(60*60*24));
?>
<p class="counter-number"><?=$datediff?></p>
```

Edit: I'm looking for a code (I'm not quite sure whether this should be done in PHP or JSCRIPT) that will count the days upwards from a certain date (the date being 18 June 2016) but I just want it to display the number of the day. So say if it's 7 days from the 12th, just to display the number 7.

The above code just shows blank space and nothing else

Comment: *"does not work"* is not a proper problem description. What does it do? How is it different than expected? See [ask]

Comment: This works perfectly: https://pgmann.cf/so/37897213/ (I'm using PHP7)

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateInterval`:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

[datetime.diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: @kamalpal `$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);` creates an `DateInterval`object.

Answer (score 0):

IF I am not mistaken you can't add PHP code in the source section of the page editor. 
You would need to add a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/ first.